# Jmeter - How to output from JSR223 PostProcessor to HMTL reporter

Tags: jmeter

I have same variables that i want to output from: JSR223 PostProcessor

[image]

To: Jmeter HTML reporter
[image]

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The only easy way I can think of which doesn't require amending JMeter code and [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.2.1/bin/report-template) is to append the variable values to the parent [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) label (name), like:

```
prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel(false) + ' | DATA as: ' + vars.get('TC_name') + ' | ' + vars.get('username') + ' | ' + vars.get('password') + ' | ' + vars.get('expecedCode'))
```

where `prev` stands for parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see the JavaDoc and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information

[image]

Comment: I tried with your sample, but still i can't see anything into the report. My goal is to execute via CMD as:  


**cd C:\Jmeter_20200428\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin && jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\test1\Desktop\RegressionPack_2020.jmx" -l "C:\Jmeter_20200428\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\logs\Client_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_logfile.csv" -e -o "C:\Jmeter_20200428\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\logs\HTML\Client_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%"**



And there to see the variables